# Таблица друзей java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Как реализовать таблицу друзей? При использовании анотаций `@ManyToMany` и `@JoinTable` я могу выгружать данные, запрашиваемые по одному столбцу.

Есть таблица `friend` с полями `friend1` и `friend2`.
Если один является другом другого, то эта связь работает и обратно (если а - друг б, то б - друг а).
Как выгружать данные о друзьях, проверяя оба столбца?

Вобщем всё что нужно: искать юзера в обоих столбцах и из противоположного забирать друга, но как это реализуется в hibernate?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял ваш вопрос, но попробую.

Предположим, у нас есть таблица `man`, описывающая человека, и соответствующий ей класс `Man`. Люди дружат в отношении *"Многие-ко-многим"*.

Первая реализация этого отношения, которая приходит на ум, - сочетание `@ManyToMany` и `@JoinTable`. Однако есть и другой способ построить отношение *"Многие-ко-многим"*: через `@ManyToOne` и `@OneToMany`.

Таблица `friend` отвечает за связывание друзей посредством столбцов `friend1` и `friend2`. Соответствующий ей класс `Friend` можно сделать таким:

```
// ...
@Entity
public class Friend {

    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend1")
    private Man firstFriend;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend2")
    private Man secondFriend;

    // ...

}
```

А класс `Man` тогда может выглядеть так:

```
// ...
@Entity
public class Man {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstFriend")
    private List<Friend> friendsFirstPart;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "secondFriend")
    private List<Friend> friendsSecondPart;

    // ...

}
```

Теперь вы берёте нужного юзера из БД по айди любым способом, и в списках `friendsFirstPart` и `friendsSecondPart` получаете суммарно всех его друзей, если они есть.

Тут у нас получается, что сущность вступает в отношение *"Многие-ко-многим"* сама с собой. Я до этого никогда такой случай не рассматривал, поэтому, возможно, приведённый мной вариант не сработает. Но теоретически должен.